# How to add a popup menu to the command bar inside visual studio 2012 via powershell

Tags: events, powershell, menu, visual-studio-2012, customization

Now I swear I had this working, but upon closing my long running visual studio session, and reopening anew, I can not get this to work and I don't know what is different than my prior session.

I'm trying to accomplish adding a custom menu and a button click event to fire a command. I was trying to get it to fire off some more powershell, however I've changed it to a command I know the dte can execute easily, which is the samples command.

Anyone see anything wrong or something I'm overlooking ( I did have it working, it does not now in a new VS session. no error is thrown but the click event isn't firing or so it seems to me.

This powershell is executed inside VS 2012

```
$menubar = $dte.CommandBars["MenuBar"]
$cmenu = $menubar.Controls.Add([Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.MsoControlType]::msoControlPopup, 1, "", 36, $true)
$cmenu.Caption = "CUSTOM"
$cmenu.Enabled = $true
$item = $cmenu.Controls.Add([Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.MsoControlType]::msoControlButton, 1, "", 1, $true)
$item.Caption = "Item"
$itemHandler = $dte.Events.CommandBarEvents($item)
$itemEvents = Get-Interface $itemHandler ([EnvDTE._dispCommandBarControlEvents_Event])
$itemClickEvent = [EnvDTE._dispCommandBarControlEvents_ClickEventHandler]{ $dte.ExecuteCommand("Help.Samples") }
$itemEvents.add_Click($itemClickEvent)
```

Comment: a side note: the invoke on the handler does work fine:  $itemClickEvent.Invoke($menubar, [ref]$true, [ref]$false)

Comment: abandoning this method -- will have to go the AddIn route